# How do I export a Google sheet as a CSV in Python without using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, google-sheets, gspread

I'm using Python 3.9 and the following version of Google Sheets ...

```
gsheets==0.5.1
gspread==3.6.0
```

I'm trying to export my Google sheet as a CSV file.  In older versions of Python, I was using the Pandas module like so

```
    import gspread
    ...
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
    sheet = client.open('My_Sheet_name')

    # get the third sheet of the Spreadsheet.  This
    # contains the data we want
    sheet_instance = sheet.get_worksheet(3)

    records_data = sheet_instance.get_all_records()

    records_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(records_data)

    # view the top records
    records_df.to_csv(sys.stdout)
```

How would I export the CSV without using Pandas?  I ask because it would seem newer versions of Python (e.g. 3.9) do not support the pandas module yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as situation as follows.

- You want to retrieve one of sheets in Google Spreadsheet as the CSV data.
- You want to achieve this using gspread without using Pandas.
- You have already been able to use gspread.

In this case, in order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose to use the endpoint for exporting the sheet as CSV data. The access token is retrieved from `client` of `client = gspread.authorize(creds)`. When this proposal is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open('My_Sheet_name')

# get the third sheet of the Spreadsheet.  This
# contains the data we want
sheet_instance = sheet.get_worksheet(2)  # Modified

# I added below script.
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + sheet.id + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=' + str(sheet_instance.id)
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + client.auth.token}
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(res.text)
```

- In above script, please add `import requests`.
- When above script is run, 3rd sheet is exported as the CSV data.

#### Note:

- About `sheet_instance = sheet.get_worksheet(3)`, your comment says `get the third sheet of the Spreadsheet.`. But the 1st number of `get_worksheet` is `0`. So in this case, 4th sheet in the Spreadsheet is retrieved. Please be careful this.
- In this case, I think that you can also use the endpoint as follows.

  ```
    url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + sheet.id + '/export?format=csv&gid=' + str(sheet_instance.id)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) from the csv module to add each dictionary as a seperate line to the csv result:

```py
import sys
from csv import DictWriter

dict_writer = DictWriter(sys.stdout, records_data[0].keys())
dict_writer.writeheader()
for data in records_data:
    dict_writer.writerow(data)
```

If you want to write the csv to a file instead of stdout, you can use this snippet instead:

```py
from csv import DictWriter

with open('./path/to/the/file', 'w') as csvfile:
    dict_writer = DictWriter(csvfile, records_data[0].keys())
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    for data in records_data:
        dict_writer.writerow(data)
```

---

**Example:**

`records_data` contains the following values: `[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}]`

Then the header is taken from the keys of an arbitrary element of the list (in this case the first one): `a` and `b`.

Then the values are added line by line to the csv:

```
a, b
1, 2
2, 3
3, 4
```

Comment: Did you mean for me to put "records_data = [dict(zip(records_data.keys(), i)) for i in zip(*records_data.values())]" after "records_data = sheet_instance.get_all_records()"?  I tried this but got the error, "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'"

Comment: @Dave The `get_all_records()` method already returns the data in the right format. So you can simply skip the first step. I will update my answer accordingly.